# Is it immoral to take something from someone who stole it from you?

Tags: ethics

I had a discussion with a friend. It was based on this scenario:
You had a bike that was very dear to you and your neighbor a few houses down stole it from you and you knew it. If this bike is standing in his garage, would it be ok to go on his property and take the bike back? This is assuming that you have no other option but to let it go, or "steal" it back.

Personally I would say that it wasn't the right thing to go on another person's property and take something, except if you had his consent, but my friend thinks it's perfectly fine to go take it back.

Comment: I agree with your friend (and you should take more stuff for compensation), but that's just a personal opinion. As a factual question, you're asking: how would different philosophers or philosophies solve this moral dilemma.

Comment: Well yea i should probably say that too, if it happenede to me for real, i sure would just take it back, but as morality go, i'd say it was stealing, which i think we can agree is wrong

Comment: The "steal it back" option is neither good or bad, it's just better or worse than others.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the user!

Comment: As "stealing" is generally thought of as "taking something that does not belong to you", I'd say it would be impossible to _steal_ back something that is rightfully yours; but at the same time, doing so in the manner you describe does not negate the _trespassing_ (though it could arguably justify it).

Comment: Really strong magnets ;)

Comment: It might even be immoral to not do it if you can do so safely/without punishment. To let someone complete the commission of the theft when you have the ability to prevent this might, according to some moral outlooks, lack virtue.

Comment: It might or might not be, & different people might dispute that, & cause more problems, like a vendetta or feud based on different perceptions of value of things involved. That is why we have due process, & 3rd party arbitrations, in order to find solutions that stick, & don't cause ongoing issues.

Answer (score 1):

I would say there is a confusion between immoral and illegal in the question.  Given the information we have, it could not be said to be immoral to take back your property from the thief, if you know for certainty. It might be illegal to trespass on his land, but not it's not immoral.

Expanding the question, what if you are wealthy and have many other bikes, but the thief is a poor man who has taken it for his child, because he can't afford the bus fare to get to school ? :)

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It's worth taking the time to read over [Kohlberg's stages of moral development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_Kohlberg%27s_stages_of_moral_development). Your friend seems to be arguing from an upper pre-conventional perspective (which emphasizes self-interest and tit-for-tat type reasoning), while you seem to be working from a lower conventional perspective (which rests on social norms and standards of propriety). On that account your position is somewhat more developed.

Don't let that go to your head; one data point isn't enough to make a general statement...

Answer (score 0):

You are not stealing, merely taking back something that belongs to you.

But it is a perspective thing. You have to trespass(you can be the judge of how bad that is) and have to take something away(which is yours).

At the end of the day I agree with your friend, because your are not doing anything wrong, you are making a wrong right again.

And the stealing from thieves scenario? That is just poetic, if the thief doesn't like it, he knows how his victims feel.